# Is custom field validation message supported on lightning-input-field like it works in lightning-input?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, validation, custom

From the document:

```
<template>
<lightning-input label="First Name"
                 minlength="5"
                 message-when-too-short="Your entry must be at least 5 characters.">
</lightning-input>
```

My question is:  like the above code, is this approach supported on **lightning-input-field** to show custom validation message? Couldn't find anything in the document.

Comment: you should probably try adding in the properties, however, if it is not specified in the documentation, I would assume it is not supported..

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in the org and as mentioned in the comment as it is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification), the results were as expected and it was not possible to use message-when-too-short or similar attributes with lightning-input-field. However, I was able to use the below sample snippet that on click of validate button validates the name and phone field. You can modify this snippet to fit your requirement.

Component:

```
<template>
<div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:500px">
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" id="createAccountForm">
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" required>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone" required>
        </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button type="submit" name="submit" label="Create Account">
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button onclick={validateFields} name="submit" label="Validate">
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</div>
</template>
```

Controller:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class RecordForm extends LightningElement {
    validateFields() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field').forEach(element => {
            element.reportValidity();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will validate, which I also do. Bit it won't show custom message as that is the requirement or reason for my question.